# Aspects of Jyotisha - Medical astrology

Tags: ayurveda, astrology, health, body

How is Jyotisha used to predict the level of health of a person?

How are Rashis, Bhavas, Grahas etc. correlated with a person's physical well-being?

Also, how is Jyotisha related to Ayurveda?

Answer (score 1):

In the universe all the creatures are related to Adhivyadhi, which indicates mental agony or bodily pain. Acharyas of Ayurveda like Charaka, Sushruta and Kashyap have classified diseases into various categories like Agantuja, Sharirika, Manasika, Swabhavika, etc. Charaka classified diseases based on the prognosis like Sadhya, Asadhya, Mrudu and Daruna. Ayurveda also suggested Daiva Vyapashraya Chikitsa which includes of Manidharana and chanting Mantras. [Astrological sciences](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3764876/) suggest 10 types of remedial measures in the treatment of diseases. This science considers that causative factors of various disorders are the Navagrahas (nine planets). The influence of the planets on various procedures like d**rug processing, bath taking, performing Yajna, wearing Ratna, etc.** are well documented in Jyotisha shastra. Drugs processed in Chandra Nakshatra acts as ambrosia and subdues Tridoshajanya Vyadhi. Medicated baths are suggested for diseases engendered due to involvement of different planet effects viz. **Sarshpa for Shukra, Haridra and Daruharidra for Shani Lodhra for Ketu, Sharpunkha for Rahu, etc.** In a close scrutiny it appears that Jyotishashastra Siddhanta can play crucial role in the management of chronic diseases.

The most wonderful feature of the Vedic astrology or jyotiSha is the availability of remedies for any problem, let it be loukika(materialistic) or AdhyAtmika(spiritual)! The solution is not a black-magic type of remedy, but vaidika(from Veda) in nature - a good for all technique. Vaidika remedies can be classified broadly into **maNi, mantra and auShadha.**

[Ayurvedic Astrology](https://vedanet.com/2012/06/13/ayurvedic-astrology/)

Yet, though they have their specializations in many areas, both Vedic astrology and Ayurveda have a significant overlap as well. Vedic astrology contains a medical system based upon Ayurveda, while Ayurveda contains a system for the timing of disease and its treatment based upon Vedic astrology. We can designate this combined usage of Ayurveda and Vedic astrology more simply as ‘Ayurvedic Astrology’.

Ayurvedic astrology is the medical branch of Vedic astrology, adding to it the Ayurvedic view of health and healing. It uses the language of Ayurveda to understand the effects of the planets on the body and mind relative to health, disease and longevity. Ayurvedic astrology also uses Vedic astrology as an aid to Ayurvedic analysis, diagnosis and treatment, showing how planetary factors cause disease and balancing them can be an important aid in any cure.

Ayurvedic astrology combines these two great disciplines, using Vedic astrology to plot the influences of time and karma and Ayurveda to show how these relate on to our state of Prana or vital energy. Combining these two great disciplines together, there is nothing that we cannot treat or cannot understand.

[THE THREE DOSHA'S](http://www.dirah.org/ayurveda.htm)

Ayurveda is based on the three constitutions, the three dosha's. These three doshas are called *vata, pitta and kapha.* Vata corresponds to air, pitta to fire, and kapha to earth and water. The astrological signs can then be divided as follows:

*Vata* : Gemini, Virgo, Libra, Capricorn and Aquarius. Virgo is placed here because it is ruled by Mercury, which is an air planet in Vedic astrology. Capricorn is mentioned here because it is ruled by the vata planet Saturn.

*Pitta* : Aries, Leo, Sagittarius and Scorpio. Scorpio is pitta because the classic ruler of Scorpio is the fire planet Mars. In Vedic astrology, Uranus, Neptune and Pluto are not used, and so Mars remains the ruler of Scorpio.

*Kapha* : Taurus, Cancer, and Pisces. These are the earth and water signs not assigned to vata and pitta.

Answer (score 1):

In astrology 6th house indicates disease and 12th house indicates hospital. Planets Sun indicates soul and health of the person. Mars is Roga karaka and Saturn is Roga bhavathipathi.

In ancient Indian culture it is considered world have five forms of energy Earth (prithvi), water, fire, Air, ether(akash). Earth is what we live upon and ether is above us so leaving these 2 human body primarily have 3 form of energy Water, Air and Fire.

Any disease is mere indication of these 3 energy imbalance. Now from astrological chart we can easily find out what imbalance can a person get during particular dasha bukti. Mars and Sun are fiery planets, Venus & Moon are watery and Saturn airy planet. Signs Aries, Leo and Sagittarius are fiery signs. Sign Cancer, Scorpio and Pieces are watery signs. Signs Gemini, Libra and Aquarius are Airy signs. Based on above planetary and Sign relationship with 6th house one can logically conclude the ailment a person will have.

Also Sun rules modern medicine and Saturn rules traditional medicine. Based on relationship of 6th lord or 6th house with Sun or Saturn we can logically conclude the person is suitable for modern medicine or traditional medicine(Ayurveda or homeopathic medicine).